# How to set an alias across all tty shells?

Tags: shell

I set an alias in shell tt2 but it won't work in other tty shells, any idea how to make a system wide alias ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't force a shell process to use new aliases from the outside, so the request to load the new aliases will have to come from each shell instance on each terminal.

You can make bash execute code after each command by putting that code in the [`PROMPT_COMMAND`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-PROMPT_005fCOMMAND) variable. So you could use something like

```
reload_aliases () {
  . ~/.bash_aliases
}
PROMPT_COMMAND="$PROMPT_COMMAND
reload_aliases"
```

and define your aliases by editing `~/.bash_aliases` instead of typing them in one shell. Note that the `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable is only executed after running a command, so you need to run one command (e.g. `:`, which is a command that does nothing); an empty command line is not enough.

You can also override the `alias` command to automatically append to the `.bash_aliases` file, but I recommend against that, because it would be very disruptive when you want to define a task-specific alias for one shell only. You can append a specific alias with its definition in the current shell with the command `alias ALIASNAME >>~/.bash_aliases` (replace `ALIASNAME` by the actual name of the alias).

In zsh, you would use [`precmd`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html#index-precmd_005ffunctions) instead of bash's `PROMPT_COMMAND`. Unlike bash's `PROMPT_COMMAND`, `precmd` is actually executed before displaying each prompt, so pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> at the prompt is enough to invoke it. Even zsh doesn't have a way to reload the alias file without user intervention.

Alternatively, you can make your shell react to a signal by setting a [`trap`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-trap). The signal SIGUSR1 isn't used by shells, so you can use that to make it load your aliases:

```
trap 'reload_aliases' USR1
```

(The `reload_aliases` function is as above.) With this approach, you need to send a SIGUSR1 signal to all *interactive* instances of your shell when you edit your alias list. Make very sure not to send the signal to scripts, because the default action for this signal is to kill the shell! There is no easy way to list interactive shells; the following Linux-specific script comes close, but be aware that it might accidentally close an unrelated process because of race conditions.

```
for pid in $(pgrep bash); do
  if cd "/proc/$pid" 2>/dev/null &&
     [ -c fd/0 ] &&
     grep '^SigCgt: .............[2367abef]..$' status; then
    kill -USR1 "$pid"
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 4):

NO need for hard works, just change the `/etc/bashrc` file. I know, you may think that it only works on current tty but no mate, it works. Just exit once and then log in again with any user you like. You can even test this through SSHing or whatsoever.

But if it didn't work - while I believe it does - read this file, this can help you much: `/etc/profile`